# Remove the parent keys from the multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array. I want to remove the parent keys [0],[1],[2] ..... What's the best way to remove the parent keys in an Multidimensional Array?. For example I have this code

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [comment_tN9l43iUjZLNap4Dbkf7w8Whb3] => Array
            (
                [required] => This field is required
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [checkbox_cNVyw1lV0eVrYdeymth2c90AW] => Array
            (
                [required] => Select Gender
                [minlength] => Please select at least 2 items.
                [maxlength] => Please select no more than 4 items.
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [checkbox_EM9tkQoZ4YMaPncAPenfi6ltB] => Array
            (
                [required] => This field is required
                [minlength] => Please select at least 1 items.
                [maxlength] => Please select no more than 3 items.
            )

    )

)
```

but i want the array like this

```
Array
    (
        [comment_tN9l43iUjZLNap4Dbkf7w8Whb3] => Array
            (
                [required] => This field is required
            )
        [checkbox_cNVyw1lV0eVrYdeymth2c90AW] => Array
            (
                [required] => Select Gender
                [minlength] => Please select at least 2 items.
                [maxlength] => Please select no more than 4 items.
            )
        [checkbox_EM9tkQoZ4YMaPncAPenfi6ltB] => Array
            (
                [required] => This field is required
                [minlength] => Please select at least 1 items.
                [maxlength] => Please select no more than 3 items.
            )

    )
```

Comment: It's impossible to do it. There is no array without keys. The second array is exactly the same as the first. You just didn't write the keys explicitly.

Comment: Yes I agree with @user4035.

Comment: The op wants to delete the numbered keys [0], [1], [2] and instead have 
[comment_tN9l43iUjZLNap4Dbkf7w8Whb3] ... as keys. He wants to change the indexed array to an associative array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy all you have to do is call [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) via [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to get the results you want.

```
$newArray = call_user_func_array("array_merge", $oldArray);
```

You can see a simplified example [here](http://3v4l.org/V1pu3)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($oldArray AS $data) {
    $newArray = array_merge($newArray, $data);
}
```

See the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/array_merge) for `array_merge()` for more information.